# Preventing an application from being moved between spaces

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon, spaces, apple-expose

Working on an application that contains legacy Carbon code (mixed with some Cocoa). It is a full screen app (not technically, it just draws itself as though it were) that hides the dock and application menu bar when active.

What I'd like to do is prevent the application from being allowed to move between Spaces. Basically, if the user attempts to use spaces the application is unmovable (or does not appear in the preview of applications at all).

Any pointers/tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't move applications between spaces; you move windows between spaces.

Thus, the solution is in [NSWindow's `collectionBehavior` property](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setCollectionBehavior:).

Comment: Yeah, I worded that wrong. But what you linked to is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!